# GET v2/entities filtering by dates

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm performing an `GET /v2/entities` query to an exisiting Orion Context Broker and I would like to filter the retrieved entities by `TimeInstant` attribute, which is in "date" format: `2019-11-14T06:00:23.00Z`. I would like to get ONLY those entities which `TimeInstant` value is > `2019-11-14T06:10:23.00Z`. I haven't found examples showing how to deal with attributes different from "int" values.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example for instance in slide 65 of [the Orion introductory presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/orion-context-broker-20191021):

```
GET /v2/entities?q=TimeInstant>2019-11-14T06:10:23.00Z
```

Note that in order that query to work, `TimeInstant` attribute must be of `DateTime` type (or `ISO8601` type, which is an alias). More information on `DateTime` type in the [NGSv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable).